# 1 форма для клиента и админа

Tags: php, html

Безопасно ли сделать для админа и клиента 1 форму авторизации? 
Тоесть обычных клиентов будет перенаправлять в личный кабинет, а админов в админ панель. Или лучше сделать разные формы?

Comment: А для модераторов еще одну, а для контенщиков еще одну, а для сеошников еще одну, а для директора еще одну))) Главное в серверной части соблюсти безопасность. А кучу форм плодить не нужно

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский,ну я думал что создам для клиентов одну форму, и одну для остальных(с преимуществом)

Comment: Я делаю две отдельные формы, тк авторизация клиента может иметь дополнительную логику работы, например авторизация через соцсети.

Comment: @Ersultan Простите, с каким преимуществом? Не понял немного)) .

Comment: @MarselArduanov Думаю, логично, что админы будут входить итак через лог пас (или через url), а не через соц сети. Так смысл тогда?))  Если через Url - то да, другая форма вполне логична

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Лучше сделать отдельную форму входа в админ панель для администраторов сайта, но не на самом сайте, а сделать отдельную папку `admin/` и там сделать форму входа которую нужно хорошо защитить.

Можно пользоваться и одной формой для пользователей и администратора, тогда нужно проверять емейл, если это админ перенаправлять в админ панель, а если пользователь перенаправлять в личный кабинет.

Comment: А не будет ли проблем с безопасностью?Нету ли риска,что хакеры перенаправятся в админ панель?Знаю что вопрос тупой,но нужно как то предостеречьсяү

Comment: @Ersultan Вы в любом случае обязаны сравнивать то, что вам пришло на сервер с формы с тем, что вы ожидаете получить от этой формы. (например с данными в БД).